# How to use an angular service into an non-angular object

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular service

```
app.factory('MyService', function($http,$q)){
    return{
        super : function(){
             return "Angular is awesome";
        }
    };
});
```

and a complex javascript object defined outside Angular's scope (controller or service):

```
var MyObject = {
    anyFunction : function(){
        alert(MyService.super());
    }
};
```

Now, doing

```
MyObject.anyFunction();
```

of course fails. Any idea how I can get MyService  injected into my external javascript object?

Answer (score 1):

This is bad way, byt you may save your angular's var to the localStorage and then acces it from legacy code, and as a second option, you may access global variable from factory, using **$window** service.

In common js:

```
var myVar;
```

In factory:

```
app.factory('MyService', ['$window', '$http', '$q',function($window, $http, $q)){
    return{
        super : function(){
            $window.myVar = 'that is it';
            //or 
            //localStorage.addItem('myVar', 'varValue');
        }
    };
}]);
```

after **MyService.super** is done, you may access var in common js as usualy before